# Использование RandomAccessFile, кодировки

Tags: java, кодировка, io, randomaccessfile

При чтении байтов из файла с использовании RandomAccessFile  нормально выводится в консоль только латиница. Чтоб выводилась нормально  кирилица необходимо выполнить следующий код.

```
String str2 = new String(str1.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF8");
```

Не могу понять. Зачем нужно сначала получать байты в кодировке ISO-8859-1, а потом перегонять их сразу в UTF8.

Comment: метод `readLine` [превращает байты в символы](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine()) используя байт из файла в качестве младшего байта `char`. `str1.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")` превращает строку таких символов обратно в байты. Альтернативой будет самостоятельный поиск переводов строк, использование `readFully` и создание строки из массива в нужной кодировке, все это нельзя просто так взять и записать в одну строку.

Comment: @zRrr , правильно ли я понимаю. При считывании байтов с файла методом readLine класса RandomAccessFile, он  преобразовует байты в символы используя кодировку "ISO-8859-1"?

Comment: он буквально [делает](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/RandomAccessFile.java#L943) `(char)read()`. Просто начало таблицы unicode совпадает с ISO-8859-1, поэтому все работает.